# SQL Server : CROSS APPLY equivalent for ROW_NUMBER() query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to find a different way to write a `ROW_NUMBER()` query using `CROSS APPLY` so I can compare the performance.

In the below simple example, an employee table is created, some test data is inserted and a `SELECT` with a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function is used to find the employee in each department with the longest tenure.

Is there another way to write the `SELECT` using a `CROSS APPLY`?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEmployee]
(
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [DeptID] [TINYINT] NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [Tenure] [TINYINT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEmployee] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.tblEmployee (ID, DeptID, EmpName, Tenure) 
VALUES ('1', '1', 'John', 2),
       ('2', '1', 'Mary', 5),
       ('3', '2', 'Joe', 3),
       ('4', '3', 'Bill', 10),
       ('5', '2', 'Marilynn', 9),
       ('6', '3', 'Sue', 7);

SELECT 
    EmpName, DeptID, Tenure 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         EmpName, DeptID, Tenure, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DeptID ORDER BY Tenure DESC) TenureRank
     FROM 
         tblEmployee) e 
WHERE 
    e.TenureRank = 1
ORDER BY 
    DeptID
```

**EDIT**: I would prefer to not use a CTE as part of the `SELECT`

Comment: There is, but you wouldn't want to.  It would be much less efficient.

Comment: What about options other than CROSS APPLY...anything potentially more efficient?

Comment: That depends. What do you want to do if two or more employees have the same tenure?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Please assume there will be no ties. I'm just using this simple example to figure out other query options. In my real life scenario, there will be no ties.

Answer (score 1):

The `cross apply` equivalent would be:

```
select e.*, a.seqnum
from tblEmployee e cross apply
     (select count(*) as seqnum
      from tblEmployee e2
      where e2.deptid = e.deptid and
            (e2.tenure > e.tenure or
             e2.tenure = e.tenure and e2.id >= e.id
            )
     ) a;
```

You would not want to do this, because it is much, much less efficient, than `row_number()`.  Note the use of `id` for the comparison to ensure unique numbers.

Comment: I think you can do a lot better with a `TOP 1` style apply... still won't likley beat row_number(), but it's sometime.

Comment: @Zack . . . No clarification is needed.  `row_number()` is quite explicit in how it behaviors.

Comment: Yes, in that it explicitly provides "no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using ROW_NUMBER() will be ordered exactly the same with each execution [with non-unique columns]". The confusion was how OP wanted to handle potential ties. Since OP states that ties aren't an issue, it's moot point anyways. :)

Comment: @Zack you might be missing the "non-unique" part of that. If the `ORDER BY` portion of the `OVER` clause is clear enough to define a strict order, the function is deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a better source for deptartment ID's than scanning the entire tblEmployee table:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DeptID FROM tblEmployee) d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 EmpName, DeptID, Tenure
    FROM tblEmployee e
    WHERE e.DeptID = d.DeptID
    ORDER BY Tenure DESC
) a
```

This particular example isn't likely to favor the `APPLY` approach, as you also need to contrive the source values.

APPLY can make more sense when you're working on a query where you already have the source data (say, you needed Department Name, too, and so you had naturally started from an imagined `tblDepartment` table). It can also do well when you need to get this kind of info from more than one place (it's much easier to have more than one APPLY in a query than ROW_NUMBER()), or when the APPLY operation is itself a more-complicated subquery, looking in several tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without either using `CROSS APPLY` or `ROWNUM`. You can create a derived table that lists the max tenure for each department, and then join that to the base employee table. Using a CTE, your query would look like this:

```
WITH 
    DeptWithMaxTenure AS
    (
        SELECT DeptID, Max(Tenure) AS MaxTenure
        FROM tblEmployee
        GROUP BY DeptID
    )
SELECT
    tblEmployee.EmpName,
    tblEmployee.DeptID,
    tblEmployee.Tenure
FROM tblEmployee
    INNER JOIN DeptWithMaxTenure ON
        DeptWithMaxTenure.DeptID = tblEmployee.DeptID
        AND DeptWithMaxTenure.MaxTenure = tblEmployee.Tenure
```

Comment: This could produce two records for a department in the cases where two employees have the same tenure.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention I'm trying to avoid using a CTE. I've had very bad experience using CTEs in a replicated environment.

Comment: @user2966445 I'm sorry to hear that. CTEs are amazing, and you should definitely give them another chance. Just maybe not this chance.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Since OP wants to "find the employee in each department with the longest tenure", I would argue that you **would** want multiple employees returned in that use case (although, of course, OP would have to clarify). If you don't want to use a CTE, you could put the table expression directly in your query. However, it really ends up being the same thing.

Comment: the row_number solution gives no tie breaker, and is therefore indeterminate where there are ties - so that is a potential problem.  Same goes for Top 1, it could give different results

Comment: Perhaps he does want that... in which case the row_number() query we're trying to match doesn't work.

Comment: Please assume there will not be ties in this simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it came out 4 times as slow as the original

```
SELECT A.EmpName, A.DeptID, A.Tenure FROM tblEmployee A 
               CROSS APPLY 
                    (SELECT TOP 1 B.ID FROM tblEmployee B 
                          WHERE B.DeptID = A.DeptID Order By Tenure Desc) CA
WHERE CA.ID = A.ID;
```

Comment: Which is more performant depends on the data distribution and the indexes. https://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/optimizing-top-n-group-queries

Comment: I was wondering if TOP 1 is more efficient than possibly having to compute all row_numbers, then selecting those that are 1 (not withstanding how clever performance optimizer might be) - i.e. we don't care about working out which is row 50,51,52.... etc - we just need the max